# Api погоды, но получить результат не текстом, а картинкой

Tags: python, api

Друзья, написал код на питоне, получающий погоду по яндекс погода апи. Всё хорошо, код работает и в тг выводит всю информацию. Видел где-то на ютубе, что кто-то получал погоду в картинке. Не помню как было реализовано, но в группу уходил прогноз погоды именно в картинке. Кто может подсказать как можно сделать аналогичное решение? Чтобы получать прогноз в картинке? Может есть какое-то api или же альтернативное решение? Спасибо!

Comment: получить данные в тексте и отрисовать на желаемой картинке

Comment: Рекомендуется дополнить вопрос. Как и в каком виде формируются выходные данные о погоде через запрос в api?